# Azure DevOps Releases - Avoid the stage approval when the release starts on scheduling

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've got a release pipeline that contains different stages, and some stages require a pre-deployment approval.
I'm trying to find a way to auto-approve one or more stages if the release is executed with a scheduling (for example, a schedule within the night), and not manually created (in this case, I want that the approval is still required).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks and regards,
Simona

Answer (score 1):

We have no method to skip or automatically approve the deployment approvals.

Once the deployment approvals have been enabled on the deploy stage, it must need the required approvers to manually approve once at least before the deployment can continue, regardless of the release was triggered by what type of triggers.